# How to remove site registration error in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile, moodle-theme

I am new to moodle, I have configured moodle on a Linux server, where there was IP address in place of the domain name. After I have replaced a subdomain name with my IP address, but then I am getting a registered site to model error.
[image]

but when I tried to register the site, I got the following error.
**The hub cannot access your site at http://dnl.mydomain.com - Unable to connect (cURL error 6). Make sure that the site is not blocking HTTP requests from AWS IP address ranges.. Your Moodle site and the hub need to be able to communicate with each another. If you are unable to register your site please email support@moodle.org**

well, If I can register site then it will be fine. But if I don't want to register my site then How can I hide this error.

Answer (score 4):

If its a local site, you can switch off the registration message by adding this to `config.php`

```
$CFG->site_is_public = false;
```

Comment: I have added in it in config.php, located at the root directory, but still getting this error, please, provide your assistance, can I hide it from css or code..?